# Can a value $c$ satisfying the Mean Value Theorem be on the interval $[a,b]$?

Tags: calculus

So the question asks to find the values of c that satisfy the conclusion of the Mean Value Theorem on the closed interval $[0,3]$.

after doing the $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} $,
I got $0$, and set the derivitive of $f$, $f'(x)=3x^2-6x$.

the zeros or x-values I got were $0$ and $2$. However, can the $c$ value only be $2$ because it is in between the interval?

Answer (score 3):

The values given to you by the mean value theorem applied to a differentiable function on the interval $[a,b]$ are in the interior of the interval (i.e. they cannot be $a$ or $b$). So $0$ is not a candidate answer.